# Triangulate unstructured grid in vtk

Tags: vtk

I work with `UnstructuredGrid` and I want to triangulate it like in Paraview (when I clicked for model).

[image]

[image]

How I can do it?

I tried `vtkDelaunay3D, vtkDelaunay2D` and `vtkTriangleFilter`.

1. `vtkDelaunay3D` :

I've transformed `UnstructuredGrid` to `vtkPolyData`, after used `vtkCleanPolyData` and `vtkDelaunay3D`. It's not worked. It's crushed with  this warning :

> vtkMath.cxx: Unable to factor linear system

2. `vtkDelaunay2D` :

Similarly I used `vtkDelaunay2D`, but result is not good for me.

3. Also I use `vtkTriangleFilter`, it's result not good for me too.

Comment: Try vtkGeometryFilter then vtkTriangleFilter. You may also need to clean it up after with vtkCleanPolyData.

Answer (score 0):

When you click (or interact) in ParaView, ParaView is rendering a simplified geometry -- not simply a triangulated geometry. The filter it uses to do that is `vtkQuadricClustering`. Apply the `vtkGeometryFilter` first to your unstructured grid to convert your vtkUnstructuredGrid to a vtkPolyData. Then connect it to `vtkQuadricClustering`. You can play with parameters in `vtkQuadricClustering` to control the simplification.